# good way to convert between ad-hoc polymorphic functions and parametric polymorphic ones

Tags: haskell, reflection, parametric-polymorphism, adhoc-polymorphism

I'm wondering if there are general ways to convert between ad-hoc polymorphic functions and parametric polymorphic ones. In other words, given an ad-hoc polymorphic function, how to implement its parametric counterpart? and what about the other way around?

take `sort` as an example. it's easy to write `sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]` in terms of `sortBy`:

```
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sort = sortBy compare
```

but the other way around seems tricky, so far the best I can do is to go a bit "object-oriented":

```
import qualified Data.List as L

data OrdVal a = OV (a -> a -> Ordering) a

instance Eq (OrdVal a) where
    (OV cmp a) == (OV _ b) = a `cmp` b == EQ

instance Ord (OrdVal a) where
    (OV cmp a) `compare` (OV _ b) = a `cmp` b

sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
sortBy cmp = map unOV . L.sort . map (OV cmp)
  where
    unOV (OV _ v) = v
```

But this sounds more like a hack than proper solution.

so I'd like to know:

1. are there better ways for this specific example?
2. what are the general techniques for converting between ad-hoc polymorphic functions and parametric ones?

Comment: If we could pass dictionaries (e.g. as in Agda implicits), this would be trivial. However, I believe that some classes/libraries exploit the fact that we can't pass dictionaries to ensure some invariants. For instance, imagine if we could call`Data.Set.insert` using a different ordering every time ...

Comment: Also note that your "hack" works in practice, but only if you never pack two distinct `cmp` functions in `OrdVal a` values. If you do, then your `Ord` instance does not satisfy the `Ord` laws.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not necessarily saying you should do this, but you *can* use [reflection](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-2.1.2) to pass around the comparison function without having to package it up with each element of the list:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
import Data.Reflection

newtype O a = O a

instance Given (a -> a -> Ordering) => Eq (O a) where
    x == y = compare x y == EQ

instance Given (a -> a -> Ordering) => Ord (O a) where
    compare (O x) (O y) = given x y
```

Given (*heh*) the above infrastructure, you can then write `sortBy` in terms of `sort` as follows:

```
import Data.Coerce
import Data.List (sort)

sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
sortBy cmp = give cmp $ from . sort . to
  where
    to :: [a] -> [O a]
    to = coerce

    from :: [O a] -> [a]
    from = coerce
```

(note that by using [`Data.Coerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html), we avoid all potential runtime cost of the `O` wrapper)

Comment: `Given` is a bit evil, and you really don't need it here. Add a phantom to the newtype and then use `Reifies` instead of `Given`, `reify` instead of `give`, and `reflect` instead of `given`.

Answer (score 6):

Cactus's answer relies on the somewhat shady `Given` class in `reflection`. It's possible, however, to use reflection without that.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, MultiParamTypeClasses, UndecidableInstances #-}

module SortReflection where

import Data.Reflection
import Data.List (sort)
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Coerce

newtype O s a = O {getO :: a}

instance Reifies s (a -> a -> Ordering) => Eq (O s a) where
  a == b = compare a b == EQ

instance Reifies s (a -> a -> Ordering) => Ord (O s a) where
  compare = coerce (reflect (Proxy :: Proxy s))

sortBy :: forall a . (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
sortBy cmp = reify cmp $
  \(_ :: Proxy s) -> coerce (sort :: [O s a] -> [O s a])
```

Examining the Core produced indicates that this compiles to a thin wrapper around `sortBy`. It looks even thinner using a `Reifies` class based on `Tagged` instead of `Proxy`, but Ed Kmett doesn't like the API that produces.

Comment: Why not use `coerce` in the `sortBy` implementation?

Comment: @Cirdec, there's no particular reason not to, if you're using it elsewhere. I didn't realize when I started out that it would be beneficial elsewhere. In any case, I generally prefer to use `#.` and `.#` where applicable rather than using `coerce` directly, as doing so tends to reduce the number of type signatures required and can make the code clearer. Even when `Data.Profunctor.Unsafe` is unavailable, those bits of the `->` instance can be copied easily.

Comment: The only type signature you need with two `coerce`s is `sort :: [O s a] -> [O s a]`. If you define `sortBy cmp = reify cmp $ \(_ :: Proxy s) -> coerce . (sort :: [O s a] -> [O s a]) . coerce` you don't have to worry about potential intermediate list allocation.